# Can't log in / supposedly file-vault

Tags: macos, filevault, login

I have a power mac, which I recently updated to Lion. I've never used a password before and yet after an unusual abortive boot (unusual boot-sequence which hanged, which I had to hard-reset) I now get a login screen, which since I've never had a login in the first place, I can't get past (tried apple-ID for instance, to no avail).

I did the usual disk scans from recovery mode (which showed no problems), so I eventually ended up having to bring it in to the local apple-reseller (no 'official' apple-stores here). He says I've enabled file-vault and that he can't get to it without the username and password.

Now I can't for the life of me figure out how this could be, and file-vault isn't exactly the kind of thing you can enable accidentally. There was a progress indicator on the unusual boot, which might kind of support this idea (of an encryption process), but otherwise I'm worried that it might not necessarily be the problem.

I've had a search around, and I can't find any similar problems, so I'm just wondering if anybody on here might know if either:

- File Vault can somehow become automatically enabled or ...
- ... some other automatic activity that could somehow bring this situation about

I want to satisfy myself that this is indeed the problem, and if so how could it have come about, so for instance I don't end up doing it again!

Comment: Does your login window look like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/8OpoB.jpg If so, you've somehow enabled FileVault. If you have the usual linen background instead, FV is not enabled.

Comment: Yeah it looks like that, so could be bad news .. so I guess what remains is to discover if there's some automatic process by which it could have been enabled ... or if it is somehow recoverable!